# Contact record open in a Console tab from Case record

Tags: formula, formula-field, console, hyperlink

On a Case record I have a contact lookup when you click on the lookup icon a page will open and in that page i have few fields like Name,Email,Phone and New Contact(Link).When I click on New Contact link a new contact page is opening on the same lookup page instead client want to open it on the primary tab of console.

New Contact formula field code:

```
HYPERLINK(
    "https://devq4.cs32.my.salesforce.com/console#https%3A%2F%2Fdevq4.cs32.my.salesforce.com%2Fsetup%2Fui%2Frecordtypeselect.jsp%3Fent%3DContact%26ekp%3D003|",
    "New Contact"
)
```

Comment: Can anyone help me out please.

Comment: There might be something in the [Salesforce Console Developer
Guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/210/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/api_console.pdf) that will help.

Answer (score 0):

I havent tested this but i found here https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008w2ZIAQ Bijay's answer from 2012 interesting so have adapted it below, this might be outdated/obsolete but at least in 2012 it seems this was a way to conditionally open links based on whether the user is in console or not.

```
HYPERLINK("javascript&colon;if(typeof(srcUp)=='function') {srcUp('/console#https%3A%2F%2Fdevq4.cs32.my.salesforce.com%2Fsetup%2Fui%2Frecordtypeselect.jsp%3Fent%3DContact%26ekp%3D003|?isdtp=vw'); } "+

"else {window.location.href='/console#https%3A%2F%2Fdevq4.cs32.my.salesforce.com%2Fsetup%2Fui%2Frecordtypeselect.jsp%3Fent%3DContact%26ekp%3D003|?isdtp=vw'}","salesforceTab", "_parent")
```